# Is there a way to directly access and manipulate a DataGridCell in a specified DataGrid? C# Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: c#, datagrid, visual-studio-2015, datagridcell

Is there a way to directly access and manipulate a DataGridCell in a specified DataGrid? C# Visual Studio 2015 Community

I would like to access specific DataGridCells, preferably using row and column, verify the content and change some attributes. Once I can get to the cell, I can do all the rest. I have been using VisualTreeHelper and can almost get there. I write "almost" because for some reason, if I insert a MessageBox.Show() between two of my steps everything works fine, except for the fact that I have a message box that I don't want. Specifically, I am populating a datagrid with one set of data and want to change the background and foreground of each cell that has data matching another set.

I go between using message boxes, console writes, and local and watch variables for debugging. What I found is that without the message box, my DataGridRowPresenter shows 0 children and fails my conditional. If I remove the conditional, it throws an index out of bounds exception. If I have the message box, it shows 0 children before the message box and 2 (which is correct with my test data) children after the message box and the rest of the method continues and does exactly what I want it to do.

Is there something (other than a message box) that I can do to allow the proper traversal of the tree? Or, preferably, is there a simpler way to get directly to the cell that I want to manipulate? It seems this would have been simple if I had the option of a DataGridViewer rather than a DataGrid.

Thank you,
Eric

P.S. there are several very similar questions answered here on StackOverflow, but each seems to be addressing something different
[How can I access the data object of a DataGridCell in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361605/how-can-i-access-the-data-object-of-a-datagridcell-in-code) - is looking to pull information after a drop, I am looking to find a cell based on row and column, not any sort of event
[Access to cell values of a DataGrid in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890076/access-to-cell-values-of-a-datagrid-in-wpf) - is a nice loop through of the cell values, but I don't seem to see how to use that process to change cell attribute (e.g. if cell content is "Smith" change the font to bold)

Here's what I've done...

```
// finds and returns a List<DependencyObject> containing datagrid row and cell based on sent datagrid, column, and row parameters
private List<DependencyObject> Get_DataGridCell_By_Index(DataGrid dataGrid, int row, int column)
{
    bool isFound = false;
    DataGridCell returnRow = new DataGridCell();
    DependencyObject returnCell = new DependencyObject();
    DependencyObject dependencyObject = dataGrid as DependencyObject;
    List<DependencyObject> returnList = new List<DependencyObject>();

    // to delete
    int dependencyObjectChildrenCount;
    // to delete

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject) && !isFound; i++)
    {
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i) is Border)
        {
            dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
            isFound = true;
        }
    }

    if (isFound)
    {
        isFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject) && !isFound; i++)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i) is ScrollViewer)
            {
                dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isFound)
    {
        isFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject) && !isFound; i++)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i) is Grid)
            {
                dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isFound)
    {
        isFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject) && !isFound; i++)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i) is ScrollContentPresenter)
            {
                dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isFound)
    {
        isFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject) && !isFound; i++)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i) is ItemsPresenter)
            {
                dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // to delete
    dependencyObjectChildrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject);
    // to delete

    if (isFound)
    {
        isFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject) && !isFound; i++)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i) is DataGridRowsPresenter)
            {
                dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // to delete
    dependencyObjectChildrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject);
    // to delete

    // to delete
    // These are variation that I tried to determine what was causing/allowing the children count to go from 0 to the correct number
    //MessageBox.Show("isFound: " + isFound + "\n" + dependencyObject.ToString() + "\nrow: " + row + "\nRowPresenterCount: " + VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject));
    MessageBox.Show("");
    //dependencyObject.ToString();
    //VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject);
    // to delete

    // to delete
    dependencyObjectChildrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject);
    // to delete

    if (isFound)
    {
        isFound = false;
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject) > row)
        {
            dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, row);
            if (dependencyObject is DataGridRow)
            {
                returnList.Add(dependencyObject);
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // to delete
    dependencyObjectChildrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject);
    // to delete

    if (isFound)
    {
        isFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject) && !isFound; i++)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i) is Border)
            {
                dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isFound)
    {
        isFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject) && !isFound; i++)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i) is SelectiveScrollingGrid)
            {
                dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isFound)
    {
        isFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject) && !isFound; i++)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i) is DataGridCellsPresenter)
            {
                dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isFound)
    {
        isFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject) && !isFound; i++)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i) is ItemsPresenter)
            {
                dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isFound)
    {
        isFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject) && !isFound; i++)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i) is DataGridCellsPanel)
            {
                dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isFound)
    {
        isFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject) && !isFound; i++)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i) is DataGridCell)
            {
                dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
                isFound = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isFound)
    {
        dependencyObject = Get_DataGrid_Sibling_Cell((DataGridCell)dependencyObject, column) as DependencyObject;
        if (dependencyObject != null)
        {
            returnList.Add(dependencyObject);
        }
    }

    return returnList;

} // end Get_DataGridCell_By_Index()
```

And I also tried this to get the row, but I got a null result

```
DataGridRow row = vasgCategoryDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution at:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0d7df388-da85-4c29-a425-925d13b17604/how-to-change-wpf-datagrid-cell-background-color-programmatically-using-c?forum=wpf

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SelectDataGridCell
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridCell cell = GetCell(1, 1, myDataGrid);
                    cell.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }

        public DataGridCell GetCell(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, DataGrid dg)
        {
            DataGridRow row = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
            DataGridCellsPresenter p = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
            DataGridCell cell = p.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(columnIndex) as DataGridCell;
            return cell;
        }

        static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
        {
            T child = default(T);
            int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
            {
                Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                child = v as T;
                if (child == null)
                {
                    child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
                }
                if (child != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return child;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (unless you not using `DataGridView`):
i hope, this help's.

```
class Bar
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestWindow Window = new TestWindow(800, 600);
        Window.ShowDialog();
    }
}

class TestWindow : Form
{
    public TestWindow(int Width, int Height)
    {
        Size = new Size(Width, Height);
        BackColor = Color.Black;
        ShowIcon = false;

        MaximizeBox = false;
        MinimizeBox = false;

        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;

        MyDataGrid = new DataGrid();
        MyDataGrid.Size = new Size(400, 200);
        MyDataGrid.DataSource = new List<DummyData> { new DummyData("AB", "AD", "AI"), new DummyData("XB", "XS", "XI"), new DummyData("UUU", "FFF", "DDD"), new DummyData("XXXX", "UUUU", "IIII") };

        Button ShowCellButton = new Button();
        ShowCellButton.Click += new EventHandler(MyButton_Click);
        ShowCellButton.Location = new Point(700, 100);
        ShowCellButton.Text = "Show Text";
        ShowCellButton.ForeColor = Color.White;
        ShowCellButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;

        Controls.Add(MyDataGrid);
        Controls.Add(ShowCellButton);
    }

    DataGrid MyDataGrid;

    public void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Text = GetCellText(ref MyDataGrid, 2, 3); // Get Text in Column 2 and Row 3
        MessageBox.Show(Text.ToString());
    }

    public struct DummyData
    {
        public DummyData(string _Key, string _Value, string _Pair)
        {
            Key = _Key;
            Value = _Value;
            Pair = _Pair;
        }

        public string this[int Index]
        {
            get
            {
                if (Index == 0)
                    return Key;
                if (Index == 1)
                    return Value;
                if (Index == 2)
                    return Pair;
                return "";
            }
            set
            {
                if (Index == 0)
                    Key = value;
                if (Index == 1)
                    Value = value;
                if (Index == 2)
                    Pair = value;

            }
        }

        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Pair { get; set; }
    }

    private string GetCellText(ref DataGrid MyDataGrid, int Column, int Row)
    {
        List<DummyData> MyData = (List<DummyData>)MyDataGrid.DataSource;

        string ReturnValue = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < MyData.ToArray().Length; i++)
        {
            DummyData Temp = MyData[Row - 1];
            return (Temp[Column - 1]);
        }

        return (ReturnValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, DataGridView seems to have been replaced by DataGrid with a different set of methods and parameters. Also, accessing the data is not the problem that I am having. I need the DataCell itself so that I can change its background and foreground (I do need to know whats in the cell so that I can do a comparison, but once I have the cell, that is not an issue).